# Magento 2: dFlip 3D FlipBook - jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I'm trying to use dFlip jquery plugin on Magento 2 with no success.

I've added the css files to the default_head_blocks.xml

The following to the requirejs-config.js:

```
"map": {
    "*": {
        'dflip_js': 'js/dflip'
    }
},
```

And this to my phtml file:

```
<script>

var dFlipLocation = "https://www.my-domain.pt/dev/testing/pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/pt_PT/";

require([
    "jquery",
    "dflip_js"
], function ($) {
    var flipBook;

    //dflip assets location is other domain or folder.. once is enough

    var pdf = "https://www.my-domain.pt/file.pdf";
    var options = {height: 500};
    flipBook = $("#flipbookContainer").flipBook(pdf, options);

});
```

I know I shouldn't use an absolute url like that but I'm just trying to get this to work.

My console is full of errors..
[image]
[image]

Anyone here got this plugin to work with magento 2?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The dFlipLocation is incorrect.. It should point to the folder where dflip contents reside. Once correct Three.js will load and it will work.. The dflip.js is getting called properly.. just the supporting libraries needs to be pointed..

If the location is proper you can always pre-load three.js through script tag.. Even that will work..